# How to enable logging for virtual hosts on tomcat6?

Tags: logging, virtualhost, tomcat6

I have established 2 domains on my tomcat 6 running on CentOS.
But now my logging is broken.
All logs except catalina.out are empty.
I would like to have one log for each domain. I found a lot of similar tasks in the web but no solution till now.
I would prefer to have the most simple solution. 
Here is my server.xml:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost=...>
  <Host name="domain1.xy.com"  appBase="/home/domain1/tomcat/webapps"
        ...
  </Host>
  <Host name="domain2.xy.com"  appBase="/home/domain2/tomcat/webapps"
        ...
  </Host>
</Engine>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it, it's quite easy: Just use the "valve" element inside the "host" element:
 
This way you can have one standard log for each domain.